# Which editions of Windows 8 support Windows To Go?

Tags: windows-8, windows-to-go

With the consumer previews of Windows 8, I was able to [install and run Windows 8 off a thumbdrive/USB hard drive](http://www.triballabs.net/2012/03/step-by-step-guide-to-install-windows-8-to-go-on-a-usb/). Is this still supported in the retail release, and can I still do this using the professional edition of Windows 8, or is this an Enterprise only feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this is still [an Enterprise only feature](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8/enterprise-edition.aspx#bk_wintogo). [From Windows For Your Business blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/business/archive/2012/04/18/introducing-windows-8-enterprise-and-enhanced-software-assurance-for-today-s-modern-workforce.aspx)

> Here’s an overview of some of the key features that will be available **exclusively to Windows 8 Enterprise customers** (and note this is not an exhaustive list):
>
> - Windows To Go is a fully manageable corporate Windows 8 desktop on a bootable external USB stick. This will allow IT organizations to support the “Bring Your Own PC” trend and businesses can give contingent staff access to the corporate environment without compromising security.

Comment: Now the question is, can someone find a different way to achieve this...

Comment: @nhinkle Create Windows to Go on any edition of Windows 7....http://tweaks.com/windows/52279/how-to-create-a-windows-to-go-usb-drive/

Comment: @Moab pssst, post it as an answer [over here](http://superuser.com/questions/490362/is-there-an-equivalent-to-windows-to-go-for-personal-use)!